# Useful Linux Podcasts

Tags: learning

I'm always looking for podcasts that can help me keep up with operating systems and development. That said, I typically listen to the [Linux Outlaws podcast](http://linuxoutlaws.com/), but was wondering if there are other Linux/Unix podcasts that many of you find helpful or informative, both with learning Linux or keeping up with the changes to it.

Comment: This should be a community wiki

Comment: When you ask uses to contribute to a list of answer, please mark the question as [community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). I converted this post.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a huge podcast guy but you might want to try [TuxRadar](http://www.tuxradar.com) It's one of the better Linux ones I've heard.

Answer (score 3):

About Linux kernel itself, there is only one: http://www.kernelpodcast.org/. Although the author is asking for help to keep up with the constant flood of lkml, it's not very regular those days.

Answer (score 3):

I've been listening to the [Going Linux podcast](http://goinglinux.com/) and find it quite easy to listen to. They cover subjects easy enough for beginners and also go deeper in following podcasts. Once a month, they play a recording of one of them answering questions about Linux on the radio. In my opinion, this is a good entry level podcast.

Answer (score 2):

Roughly weekly, Randal Schwartz puts out an episode of [FLOSS Weekly](http://twit.tv/floss). This will take a look at some Free Software project by inviting a leader in the project on to answer questions. Common that I've noticed are:

- What does it do?
- Who started it?
- How mature is it?
- What license is it under? Does the leader being interviewed know why it's under that one?
- How did interviewee get involved with the project?

Answer (score 0):

Two links from me:

- [Sourcetrunk](http://www.sourcetrunk.com/) - in each episode author presents some useful free software applications. Even some old episodes are worth to listen - sometime you could find some interesting application...
- [The Linux Action Show!](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/?cat=4) - it's been a long time since last time when I listened this one, but if I remember correctly it was news about Linux software and hardware...

Answer (score 0):

A great one I listen to regularly is [The Linux Action Show](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/show/linuxactionshow/). The presenter of the show talks so fast, you get way more facts/hour than any other linux podcast... funny in places too.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the ones already mentioned, I also listen to the following:

[Sunday Morning Linux Review](http://smlr.us/) - talks about the Linux kernel, news, distros, reviews and even quizzes; very useful and enjoyable podcast

[Linux Voice](http://www.linuxvoice.com/category/podcasts/) - the guys that left Linux Format magazine - and thus the related TuxRadar podcast - started a new magazine and podcast called Linux Voice (for a small period, it was called Linux Lifestyle)

[mintCast](http://mintcast.org/) - although the guys are Linux Mint fans, they cover news, tips & reviews about all that's Linux

[Free As In Freedom](http://faif.us/) - not necessarily a Linux podcast, but you might find it interesting, being a podcast about political and legal issues in open-source software which people don't talk about very often

[Linux Luddites](http://linuxluddites.com/) - a new Linux podcast, but seems very promising; from their description: "we try all the latest free and open source software and then decide that we like the old stuff better."

[DistroCast](http://distrocast.org/) - reviews of Linux distributions, but they have been inactive for some time

Answer (score 0):

Hope you like this:

http://embedded.fm/

It mainly focuses on embeded; But it always has some references on linux.